# How do i embed music on my website using CSS while using an m4a sound file? And still having controls?

Tags: html, css, audio, embed

I want to embed music on my page using HTML/CSS while being able to have the sound file type as a .M4A. I have tried this again and again and it doesnt work. Please help!

Comment: Use a flash plugin of some sort. HTML5 does not support .m4a.

Comment: I am not using HTML5, i am using plain HTML. My friend actually used a .m4a and it works, but i want to use my own music.

Comment: Please post the code you and your friend are using.

Comment: Friends code: <p align="center">
<embed width="44" height="40" src="http://www.legotwpfire.com/09%20Show%20Me%20Your%20Firetruck.m4a" align="left"></p>

Comment: My code: <p align="center">
<embed width="44" height="40" src="A March For Fireman.m4a" autoplay="true" align="left"></p>

Comment: `<embed>` is a flash plugin. And the way you are referencing the music file may be incorrect, depending on where the .m4a file is in relation to your HTML document.

Comment: Ok. The music file is in the same folder as all of my HTML/CSS documents in its own folder. Is there a solution?

Comment: A tip on filename conventions on websites would be to never put spaces in your filename, or capital letters, or special characters. So your filename would be better as 'a_march_for_fireman.m4a'

Comment: The filename change doesnt help. I dont really want to use a Flash Player plugin for my site because then anyone without flash cant hear the song.

Comment: Can someone please help me? I really need to embed this music onto my site.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at JW Player: http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/